# not able to use submit button for more than once

Tags: php, arrays

want to insert values from text fields into multidimensional array
the code is as following:-

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<h1>Task<h1>
<br/>
<h4>Date:<h4>
    <input type="date" name="date" value=""/>
    <br/>
    <h4>Status:<h4>
    <textarea name="status"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit"name="submit" text="submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    $datewise_status=array();
    $int=0;
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $datewise_status[$_POST['date']]="".$_POST['status']."";
    }
    print($int);
    print_r($datewise_status);

    ?>
</body>
```

gives the following output:

Int value =  0
array =  Array ( [2015-06-09] => sadfasdfas )
input date = -015-06-09
text field:- sadfasdfas

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: I've been trying to add new values into array by clicking a button into above code, but i don't think it is working because no matter how many times i click the button the values are only inserted into the index-0 the values change at index-0 but are not added into the variable @Luthando Loot

Comment: check out my answer below @Vikas Tiwari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this easy with jquery, if you change your `input type` from `submit` to `button`. but if you want to to it with php, all you have to do is to change your array variable into session array:

```
<?php
 session_start();//at the beginning of the file

if(!isset($_SESSION['datewise_status'])) //check if array was already created
       $_SESSION['datewise_status']=array();
$int=0;
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $_SESSION['datewise_status'][]= array($_POST['date'],$_POST['status']);
}
print($int);
print_r($_SESSION['datewise_status']);

?>
```

Your code is not working now because you are creating a new array variable every-time you click submit

Comment: @VikasTiwari if this has solved your question please mark it as accepted by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself

Comment: No @Luthando Loot problem has not solved yet i turned the variable into session variable (using the exactly same code as you wrote above) however it takes the value in its first index and I am not able to add more values into it.($_SESSION['datewise_status']).

Comment: Is It because I have not created a session ??

Comment: @VikasTiwari sorry for responding late, please try this `$_SESSION['datewise_status'][]= array($_POST['date'],$_POST['status']);`

Comment: it works but there is one little question that I have into my mind what if I want to use date as an index of an array status I am very close to the I got output:-Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-11 [1] => prompted) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-15 [1] => completed) ) and output that I want is Array(Array([2015-06-11 ]=>prompted)Array([ 2015-06-15]=>completed))

Comment: I changed code to  $_SESSION['datewise_status'][]= array($_POST['date']=>"".$_POST['status']."");